# Why is my code generating an extra query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, will-paginate

I have the following code in my controller :

```
@unanswered_questions = Question.unanswered_with_tag(params[:tag_id]).paginate(per_page: 10, page: params[:page])
```

Which calls this method in my `Question` model:

```
def self.unanswered_with_tag id
  joins(:taggings).where(taggings: { tag_id: id }).where(questions: { num_answers: 0})
end
```

I expect one sql query that fetches the first 10 unanswered questions on that page, but my logs are showing 2 queries:

```
 Question Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "questions".* FROM "questions"  
 INNER JOIN "taggings" ON "taggings"."question_id" = "questions"."id" 
 WHERE "taggings"."tag_id" = $1 AND "questions"."num_answers" = $2 
 ORDER BY "questions"."id" ASC LIMIT $3 OFFSET $4  
 [["tag_id", 3], ["num_answers", 0], ["LIMIT", 1], ["OFFSET", 0]]
```

^^Note the `LIMIT 1` part.

And the second query :

```
 SELECT  "questions".* FROM "questions" INNER JOIN "taggings"  
   ON "taggings"."question_id" = "questions"."id" 
   WHERE "taggings"."tag_id" = $1 AND "questions"."num_answers" = $2 
   LIMIT $3 OFFSET $4  
   [["tag_id", 3], ["num_answers", 0], ["LIMIT", 10], ["OFFSET", 0]]
```

Which has LIMIT 10.

Why is this behaviour?

Comment: Have you tried combining your `.where` clauses?

Comment: Note on `ORDER BY "questions"."id" ASC` part - the code provided has no ordering, you need to find the code that do ordering. There could be implicit ordering by id though when you call `first` on relation.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running code in your view that checks whether @unanswered_questions has any rows at all (#exists? for example) to either display the values or not?